# Do QWidgets emits a signal when moved?

Tags: qt, signals, qwidget

I need to know when a QWidget is being moved (when its x or y properties are changed). Is there any signal for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no signal for that, but there is an event handler you can override for your own widget: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#moveEvent

Answer (score 1):

```
void MainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *event) {
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString::number(x())+","+QString::number(y())+"     "+QString::number(width())+","+QString::number(height()));
}
```